# How to keep a python 3 script (Bot) running

Tags: python, api, bots

*(Not native English, sorry for probably broken English. I'm also a newbie at programming).*
Hello, I'm trying to connect to a TeamSpeak server using the QueryServer to make a bot. After days of struggling with it... it works, with only 1 problem, and I'm stuck with that one.

If you need to check, this is the TeamSpeak API that I'm using: http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html

And this is the summary of what actually happens in my script:

1. It connects.
2. It checks for channel ID (and it's own client ID)
3. It joins the channel
4. Script ends so it disconnects.

My question is: How can I make it doesn't disconnects? How can I make the script stay in a "waiting" state so it can read if someone types "hi bot" in the channel? All the code needed to read texts and answer to them seems easy to program, however I'm facing a problem where I can't keep the bot "running" since it closes the file as soon as it ends running the script.

**More info:**
I am using **Python 3.4.1**.
I tried learning Threading http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm but either M'm dumb or it doesn't work the way I though it would.
In the API there's a function named `on_event` that I would like to keep running all the time. The bot code should only be run once and then stay "waiting" until an event happens. How should i do that? No clue.

**Code:**

```
import ts3
import telnetlib
import time

class BotPrincipal:
    def Conectar(ts3conn):
        MiID = [i["client_id"] for i in ts3conn.whoami()]
        ChannelToJoin = "[Pruebas] Bots"
        ts3conn.on_event = BotPrincipal.EventHappened()
        try: 
            BuscandoIDCanal = ts3conn.channelfind(pattern=ChannelToJoin) 
            IDCanal = [i["cid"] for i in BuscandoIDCanal]
            if not IDCanal: 
                print("No channel found with that name")
                return None
            else:
                MiID = str(MiID).replace("'", "")
                MiID = str(MiID).replace("]", "")
                MiID = str(MiID).replace("[", "")
                IDCanal = str(IDCanal).replace("'", "")
                IDCanal = str(IDCanal).replace("]", "")
                IDCanal = str(IDCanal).replace("[", "")                
                print("ID de canal " + ChannelToJoin + ": " + IDCanal)
                print("ID de cliente " + Nickname + ": " + MiID)
            try:
                print("Moving you into: " + ChannelToJoin)
                ts3conn.clientmove(cid=IDCanal, clid=MiID) #entra al canal
                try:
                    print("Asking for notifications from: " + ChannelToJoin)
                    ts3conn.servernotifyregister(event="channel", id_=IDCanal)
                    ts3conn.servernotifyregister(event="textchannel", id_=IDCanal)
                except ts3.query.TS3QueryError:
                    print("You have no permission to use the telnet command: servernotifyregister")
                print("------- Bot Listo -------")
            except ts3.query.TS3QueryError:
                print("You have no permission to use the telnet command: clientmove")
        except ts3.query.TS3QueryError:
            print("Error finding ID for " + ChannelToJoin + ". telnet: channelfind")

    def EventHappened():
        print("Doesn't work")

# Data needed #
USER = "thisisafakename"
PASS = "something"
HOST = "111.111.111.111"
PORT = 10011
SID = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    with ts3.query.TS3Connection(HOST, PORT) as ts3conn:
        ts3conn.login(client_login_name=USER, client_login_password=PASS)
        ts3conn.use(sid=SID)
        print("Connected to "+HOST)
        BotPrincipal.Conectar(ts3conn)
```

Comment: As a side note, this is not how you use classes. Your `Conectar` should take a `self` parameter, and your main code should construct a `BotPrincipal` instance and call the `Conectar` method on that instance, etc. It's a combination of 3 bugs canceling out that makes this sort of work, which is probably not something you want to rely on.

Comment: Just adding to abarnets note, just take a look at [Python's official documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) or some [different tutorials](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Classes).

Comment: As i never really learnt any programming language and i'm trying my best with just google, i can see where I failed. I'm checking that website right now and trying to fix the issues. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glimpse at the API, it looks like you need to explicitly tell the `ts3conn` object to wait for events. There seem to be a few ways to do it, but [`ts3conn.recv(True)`](http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html#ts3.query.TS3BaseConnection.recv) seems like the most obvious:

> Blocks untill all unfetched responses have been received or forever, if `recv_forever` is true.

Presumably as each command comes in, it will call your `on_event` handler, then when you return from that it will go back to waiting forever for the next command.

I don't know if you need threads here or not, but the docs for [`recv_in_thread`](http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html#ts3.query.TS3BaseConnection.recv_in_thread) make it sound like you might:

> Calls `recv()` in a thread. This is useful, if you used `servernotifyregister` and you expect to receive events.

You presumably want to get both servernotify events and also commands, and I guess the way this library is written you need threads for that? If so, just call `ts3conn.recv_in_thread()` instead of `ts3conn.recv(True)`. (If you look at [the source](http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/ts3/query.html#TS3BaseConnection.recv_in_thread), all that does is start a background thread and call `self.recv(True)` on that thread.)

Comment: Let me see if i understood this. I should call ts3conn.recv_in_thread() inside def EventHappened(): and it will create its own thread, so i don't need to do it myself?

Comment: @Saelyth: Not inside `EventHappened`, either at the end of `Conectar`, or in your main code after `Conectar` returns. And yes, it creates its own thread, so you don't have to. Unless you're trying to do stuff in your handler(s) that rely on mutating global or otherwise shared variables, you shouldn't even have to worry about the fact that threads exist.

Comment: I got a question related to this. Now the bot reads the telnet console events in a thread (which is perfect) but if I ask the bot to do anything else, it stops reading and it seems to close the thread (i think). I used something like "if you read X then sendmessage Y". But after that, it won't wait for events anymore. From the API, I can't seem to understand why the on_event stops working.

Comment: @Saelyth: If you have a new question, you should probably ask a new answer. Especially since I know nothing about this API, and a new question might attract an answer from someone who does. But if the thread is ending, it may be that you have to call `recv_in_thread` again after each message?

Comment: Did it. I also tried to use classes as I should (i think, I really appreciate the help), link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490533/python-3-bot-script-stops-working