# Python 3 (Bot) script stops working

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect to a TeamSpeak server using the QueryServer to make a bot. I've taken advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431647/how-to-keep-a-python-3-script-bot-running), however I still need help.

This is [The TeamSpeak API](http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html) that I'm using.

Before the edits, this was the summary of what actually happened in my script (1 connection):

1. It connects.
2. It checks for channel ID (and it's own client ID)
3. It joins the channel and starts reading everything
4. If someone says an specific command, it executes the command and then it disconnects.

How can I make it so it doesn't disconnect? How can I make the script stay in a "waiting" state so it can keep reading after the command is executed?

I am using **Python 3.4.1**.
I tried learning Threading but either I'm dumb or it doesn't work the way I thought it would. There's another "bug", once waiting for events, if I don't trigger anything with a command, it disconnects after 60 seconds.

```
#Librerias
import ts3
import threading
import datetime
from random import choice, sample

# Data needed #
USER = "thisisafakename"
PASS = "something"
HOST = "111.111.111.111"
PORT = 10011
SID = 1


class BotPrincipal:
    def __init__(self, manejador=False):
        self.ts3conn = ts3.query.TS3Connection(HOST, PORT)
        self.ts3conn.login(client_login_name=USER, client_login_password=PASS)
        self.ts3conn.use(sid=SID)
        channelToJoin = Bot.GettingChannelID("TestingBot")
        try: #Login with a client that is ok
            self.ts3conn.clientupdate(client_nickname="The Reader Bot")
            self.MyData = self.GettingMyData()
            self.MoveUserToChannel(ChannelToJoin, Bot.MyData["client_id"])
            self.suscribirEvento("textchannel", ChannelToJoin)
            self.ts3conn.on_event = self.manejadorDeEventos
            self.ts3conn.recv_in_thread()
        except ts3.query.TS3QueryError: #Name already exists, 2nd client connect with this info
            self.ts3conn.clientupdate(client_nickname="The Writer Bot")
            self.MyData = self.GettingMyData()
            self.MoveUserToChannel(ChannelToJoin, Bot.MyData["client_id"])

    def __del__(self):
        self.ts3conn.close()

    def GettingMyData(self):
        respuesta = self.ts3conn.whoami()
        return respuesta.parsed[0]

    def GettingChannelID(self, nombre):
        respuesta = self.ts3conn.channelfind(pattern=ts3.escape.TS3Escape.unescape(nombre))
        return respuesta.parsed[0]["cid"]

    def MoveUserToChannel(self, idCanal, idUsuario, passCanal=None):
        self.ts3conn.clientmove(cid=idCanal, clid=idUsuario, cpw=passCanal)

    def suscribirEvento(self, tipoEvento, idCanal):
        self.ts3conn.servernotifyregister(event=tipoEvento, id_=idCanal)

    def SendTextToChannel(self, idCanal, mensajito="Error"):
        self.ts3conn.sendtextmessage(targetmode=2, target=idCanal, msg=mensajito) #This works
        print("test") #PROBLEM HERE This doesn't work. Why? the line above did work

    def manejadorDeEventos(sender, event):
        message = event.parsed[0]['msg']
        if "test" in message: #This works
            Bot.SendTextToChannel(ChannelToJoin, "This is a test") #This works


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Bot = BotPrincipal()
    threadprincipal = threading.Thread(target=Bot.__init__)
    threadprincipal.start()
```

Prior to using 2 bots, I tested to launch the SendTextToChannel when it connects and it works perfectly, allowing me to do anything that I want after it sends the text to the channel. The bug that made entire python code stop only happens if it's triggered by the manejadorDeEventos

**Edit 1 - Experimenting with threading.**
I messed it up big time with threading, getting to the result where 2 clients connect at same time. Somehow i think 1 of them is reading the events and the other one is answering. The script doesn't close itself anymore and that's a win, but having a clone connection doesn't looks good.

**Edit 2 - Updated code and actual state of the problem.**
I managed to make the double connection works more or less "fine", but it disconnects if nothing happens in the room for 60 seconds. Tried using Threading.timer but I'm unable to make it works. The entire question code has been updated for it.

I would like an answer that helps me to do both reading from the channel and answering to it without the need of connect a second bot for it (like it's actually doing...) And I would give extra points if the answer also helps me to understand an easy way to make a query to the server each 50 seconds so it doesn't disconnects.

Comment: @Parker: This is updated code, with a new problem, not a duplicate. However, to the OP: it's worth trying to figure out ways to make that clearer, because a lot of people will have that immediate reaction. I'm not sure exactly how to do that, especially when English isn't your first language… maybe the FAQ has some guidance?

Comment: For future reference OP, it really is worth it to code stuff like this in a local git repository, or at the very least just making backups of source files before you make big modifications to source.  I've made very similar mistakes such as this one with projects and they all go away with backups/source management.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [the source](http://py-ts3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/ts3/query.html#TS3BaseConnection.recv_in_thread), `recv_in_thread` doesn't create a thread that loops around receiving messages until quit time, it creates a thread that receives a single message and then exits:

```
def recv_in_thread(self):
    """
    Calls :meth:`recv` in a thread. This is useful,
    if you used ``servernotifyregister`` and you expect to receive events.
    """
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.recv, args=(True,))
    thread.start()
    return None
```

That implies that you have to repeatedly call `recv_in_thread`, not just call it once.

I'm not sure exactly *where* to do so from reading the docs, but presumably it's at the end of whatever callback gets triggered by a received event; I think that's your `manejadorDeEventos` method? (Or maybe it's something related to the `servernotifyregister` method? I'm not sure what `servernotifyregister` is for and what `on_event` is for…)

---

That `manejadorDeEventos` brings up two side points:

- You've declared `manejadorDeEventos` wrong. Every method has to take `self` as its first parameter. When you pass a bound method, like `self.manejadorDeEventos`, that bound `self` object is going to be passed as the first argument, before any arguments that the caller passes. (There are exceptions to this for `classmethod`s and `staticmethod`s, but those don't apply here.) Also, within that method, you should almost certainly be accessing `self`, not a global variable `Bot` that happens to be the same object as `self`.
- If `manejadorDeEventos` is actually the callback for `recv_in_thread`, you've got a race condition here: if the first message comes in before your main threads finishes the `on_event` assignment, the `recv_on_thread` won't be able to call your event handler. (This is exactly the kind of bug that often shows up one time in a million, making it a huge pain to debug when you discover it months after deploying or publishing your code.) So, reverse those two lines.

---

One last thing: a brief glimpse at this library's code is a bit worrisome. It doesn't look like it's written by someone who really knows what they're doing. The method I copied above only has 3 lines of code, but it includes a useless `return None` and a leaked `Thread` that can never be `join`ed, not to mention that the whole design of making you call this method (and spawn a new thread) after each event received is weird, and even more so given that it's not really explained. If this is the standard client library for a service you have to use, then you really don't have much choice in the matter, but if it's not, I'd consider looking for a different library.

Comment: i can't call recv_in_thread again because it's the python code what stops, not the data being send to my computer. I kinda forced it to call it again and the error is "already receiving messages" as expected. What i don't get is why the entire python code stops in the SendTextToChannel section that even the Print function stops working, like if it wasn't part of the script.

Comment: @Saelyth: OK, that looks like a different problem. All of the `send*` methods block until they get a response. If there's no problem with your code starting to handle one message before finishing with a previous one, there's an easy fix to this: just call `recv_in_thread` before calling `sendtextmessage` (or, better, before you dispatch to `sendtextmessage`). That will kick off a new thread to wait for the next response. (Alternatively, you can run your own thread, and have it call `recv` repeatedly in a loop, so you don't need to keep kicking it off after each receive.)

Comment: That won't work, this happens if I try: http://prntscr.com/4ypm0x I also tried to run a main thread myself and it kinda works since i was able to ask for different commands in the chat of the Bot and the python code didn't closed itself. However, i noticed that it was actually logging everything i was saying but not sending text to chat. So it was the other way around to my actual problem, it was executing the print but Not the line above it. Frustrating...

Comment: Editted the original post, at the end, seems I think it's easier to understand it that way.